# Access Camera in Same View

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

When we use `UIImagePickerController` to get camera action  we need to open it in different viewController like as:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagepicker;
[self presentModalViewController:imagepicker animated:YES];
```

but I want to use this in same View controller from where this `UIImagePickerController` is called in different View.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a view where you want the image picker to appear say destView.
Create the image picker and then use [destView addSubview: imagepicker.view]
You may need to play with size of destView to get things right.